# Event firing twice from Angular2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having trouble with a setter method firing twice. My child component has a form where setting value of `videoId` will also set the value of `frame`.

There is also an input that allows you to set the value of `frame`.

When I set `videoId` in the child componet via the html input, the setter for `frame` in the child component fires twice. I put in some logic that checks some values to prevent the event emitter ( `this.frameChange.emit(frame)` ) from firing twice since this makes an API call in the parent component. This is just a bandaid and I have reached its limitations.

If I put a breakpoint in the `frame` setter on the child component, the call stack says the following for the first firing...

```
=> set                                   frame.controls.component.ts:52
   FrameControlsComponent.onSubmit          frame.controls.component.ts:52`
   View_FrameControlsComponent0.handleEvent_0   /SuperApp...factory.js:546
   ...
```

and the second firing...

```
=> set                                   frame.controls.component.ts:52
Wrapper_FrameControlsComponent.check_frame (/SuperAppModule/FrameControlsComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:31)
View_SuperAppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/SuperAppModule/SuperAppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:393)
AppView.detectChanges (view.js:438)
DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:633)
AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:423)
View_SuperAppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/SuperAppModule/SuperAppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30)
AppView.detectChanges (view.js:438)
DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:633)
ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:71)
View_Pages0.detectChangesInternal (/PagesModule/Pages/component.ngfactory.js:98)
AppView.detectChanges (view.js:438)
DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:633)
AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:423)
View_Pages_Host0.detectChangesInternal 
...
```

(There are more to both stack traces, let me know if I cut them off too soon.)

The logic I have put in place to handle this is not sustainable and I really need to find the root of why these events are firing twice. I understand the origin of the first call, but not the second coming from `Wrapper_FrameControlsComponent.check_frame`

Below is the relevant code

```
<!-- PARENT HTML -->
<div class="card w-100 card-panel">
  ...
  <frame-controls [(videoId)]="videoId"  [(frame)]="frame"></frame-controls>
  ...
</div>

------

<!-- CHILD HTML -->
<input class="form-control" type="number" step="1" placeholder="ID"
           id="videoId" name="videoId" #videoId="ngModel"
           [ngModel]="model.videoId" (ngModelChange)="setVideoId($event)">

<input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Number"
                 id="frame" name="frame" #frame="ngModel"
                 [(ngModel)]="model.frame">
```

...

```
// PARENT COMPONENT

@Component({
  selector: 'super-app',
  ...
  host: {
    '(window:keydown)': 'handleKeyDown($event)',
    '(window:keyup)': 'handleKeyUp($event)'
  }
})
export class SuperAppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container') private elContainer: ElementRef;

  private _frame: number;
  get frame(): number {
    return this._frame;
  }

  set frame(frame: number) {
    this._frame = frame;
  }

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument, ...) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}


// CHILD COMPONENT

@Component({
  selector: 'frame-controls',
  ...
})
export class FrameControlsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() frameChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  public model = {
    videoId: undefined,
    frame: undefined,
  };

  private _videoId: number;
  @Input()
  get videoId(): number {
    return this._videoId;
  }

  set videoId(videoId: number) {
    if (!_.isUndefined(videoId) && (videoId !== this._videoId)) {
      this._videoId = videoId;
      this.model.videoId = videoId;
      this.videoIdChange.emit(videoId);
      ...
    }
  }

  private _frame: number;
  @Input()
  get frame(): number {
    return this._frame;
  }

  set frame(frame: number) {
    if ( !_.isUndefined(frame) && this._frame != frame ) {  // TODO WHY DOES THIS FIRE TWICE THIS LOGIC IS HACKY AND DOES NOT WORK FOR ALL SCENARIOS
      this._frame = frame;
      this.model.frame = frame + 1;
      this.frameChange.emit(frame);
    }
  }

  constructor(...) {
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    if (this.videoId !== this.model.videoId) {
      this.videoId = this.model.videoId;
    }
    if (this.frame !== this.model.frame) {
      this.frame = this.model.frame - 1;
    }
  }

  public setVideoId(videoId: number) {
    this.model.videoId = videoId;
    this.model.frame = 1;
  }

  public setFrame(frame: number) {
    frame = _.clamp(frame, 1, this.maxFrames);
    this.frame = frame - 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can have one property name for both an @Input and an @Output. In here, `<frame-controls [(videoId)]="videoId"  [(frame)]="frame"></frame-controls>` you are using `videoId` (and `frame` as well) as both an input and an output by declaring like this [(videoId)]. You should use a separate EventEmitter property if you need one. Also, you only have an @Input property named for `videoId` in the child component (as a getter). Also, if you assign this, `[(videoId)]="videoId"`, then there should be a property equivalent to `videoId` (right-side) in parent component.

Comment: Probably need cleaning up of your code based on this `Input` and `Output` property assignments (both left-side, the source and the right-side, the target)

Comment: If you do need same name for both `@Input` and `@Output` properties, then follow the conventions mentioned [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#creating-custom-two-way-data-bindings).